# I am getting The operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: dart

DataCell(
//ToDo: Calculate the total price for all items

Text(items.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element.itemPrice).toString() ),
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the datatype of `previousValue`

Like so:

```
 items.fold<double>(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element)
```